# String operations on xml nodes in Python

Tags: python, string, xml-parsing

I am reading an xml file and want to perform string operations on the node's content.

```
import os
import elementtree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import tostring

xml_file = os.path.abspath(__file__)
xml_file = os.path.dirname(xml_file)
xml_file = os.path.join(xml_file, "Small1Review.xml")
print xml_file

root = ET.parse(xml_file).getroot()
text = tostring(root)
#print text

for a in text:
    #print a, "-->", a.text
    text = tostring(a)
    print text
```

But the code gives the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myEtXML.py", line 33, in <module>
    text = tostring(a)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1009, in tostring
    ElementTree(element).write(file, encoding)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 543, in __init__
    assert element is None or iselement(element)
AssertionError
```

How can I parse each node and perform some string operations on each of them.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written `for a in text`, but `text` is a string and you're treating it like an XML node.

The `tostring` method takes an `etree.Element`, but in this case `a` is a character of your string `text`.

If you want to iterate over the tree, just treat it as a list

```
root = ET.parse(xml_file).getroot()
for child in root:
    print tostring(child)
```

Also, your comment `#print a, "-->", a.text` seems to indicate that you want the `text` attribute of your nodes. This is not what's returned by the `tostring` method. The `tostring` method takes a node and makes an XML style string out of it. If you want the text attribute, just use `a.text`.